# Gmail switch accounts - How to save accounts?

Tags: gmail

I recently discovered Google "Switch Accounts" feature.  It works great and is pretty much what I need ... however I have to log in to the accounts I want to switch between each browsing session.

Is there an easy way to save this data so that my default account is always linked with my other accounts?

Also if anyone has any other nice tricks to use two accounts simultaneously in Chrome, I love to know.

Comment: You can open two different gmail accounts in chrome by opening one in normal mode and the other one in _incognito_ mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, we don't have this feature right now. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Google accounts page](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/ManageAccount) and enable multiple sign-in.

Answer (score 1):

I tested a bunch of ways: log in, reverse the logins, disassociated the multiple sign-in then added it back, all the methods [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-multiple-signin/19631/) - no luck. I get the same results as you: if I log out of all my accounts, the accounts get disassociated.

I leave my computer running and rarely close my browser, so I had not noticed this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have a personal Gmail account as well as a Google Apps account from my employer.

Since I don't want to have to switch back and forth (for the reasons you've already mentioned) I simply run separate browsers.

I do all of my personal browsing *et cetera* in Chrome, including my personal Gmail. For all of my work-related things I use Firefox. No need for switching back and forth.

(I do web development by trade, so I need to have multiple browsers installed anyway. Even so, browsers are free, and I've not run in to any problems with four different browsers running at one time.)